# Add annotation to map and open view

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

I've searched through all of internet and haven't found any solution to my (what appears to be) simple problem. I have a map where the user can add an annotation to the map when tapping on it. Here's my setup:

```
// Tap to set location
@IBAction func mapPoint(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Retrieve coordinates
    let location = sender.location(in: self.mapView)
    let locCoord = self.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.mapView)

    // Create pin
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = locCoord
    annotation.title = "Meeting Point"

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {

        // Open view here
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Map", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! MapControllerMeet
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

When the user adds an annotation i want a new view to open modally over the map, in other words i want to assign an action + a segue to my gesture recognizer. Is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: show the controller in [mapView(_:didAdd:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452311-mapview?changes=_1)

Comment: This seems like it should work. I'm fairly new to coding tho and am kinda lost on how to implement this information in my code. Could you give an example on how to do this?

Comment: my comment was a link click on it and read and when you face a problem get back here

Comment: Hi, i tried this but it still doesn't work. I edited the code in my original post, could you check it out and see what i got wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? do you get an error?

Comment: The second view doesn't open when i drop a pin on the map.

Comment: and no error at all no logs?

Comment: No no errors at all, everything runs fine. I only get the log message "Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4" but i don't think that is related.

Comment: I figured it out!! I simply had the classes setup wrong in my storyboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:`. This method is called after the annotation views have been added .

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    // Open view here

    // You can also get added annotation
    let annotationView = views.first
    print(annotationView?.annotation?.title)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VC with a transparent background , give it id and call this function end of the gesture one

```
func showModal() {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popUpId") as! popUpViewController 
    vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    vc.definesPresentationContext = true 
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've implemented the function but the second VC still doesn't show up, only the pin does.

Comment: If you are on a phone .overCurrentContext is a fullscreen display so it will not make any difference unless you run it on an iPad